# Who Bought This Also Bought in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I run an affiliated website that is related to the electronics. As I see at Amazon, there is a row of products at the end of description of every product that is "Peoples also bought these items after buying this". I also want this feature on my website. need someone to recommend any Extension for this thing please.

Comment: I wrote a [module](https://marketplace.magento.com/vct-alsobought.html#maincontent) that allows you to add a similar block of products. However, the principle by which products are added is different. Instead of **Peoples also bought these items after buying this**, it adds **Who Bought This Also Bought** (Frequently Bought Together) products.